# How to make a copy of a file between users of different domains?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to make a copy of a Google Spreadsheet file between users that are not on the same domain. The source file has a *sharing setting* of **Anyone with the link can edit**.
I created a Web App (with execution permissions set to *User accessing the web app*) that call an install function:

I was hoping the code would read the source file which is open to everybody and make a local copy to the Google Drive of the user running the Web  App (of course assuming the user accept to run the script). The behavior works when it's me running it (because I am the owner of the source) but do not work if the user is from another domain.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
function doInstall() {
// The source file is readable by everybody with the link;
  var file = DocsList.getFileById('0AlVPTKz1xoevdHc1ZTQ2OGFMXXXXXXXYYYYZZZZ');
  file.makeCopy('Test Copy Spreadsheet');
}
```

Comment: I believe your code should work since the spreadsheet is accessible to all. The only other thing I can think of is if the domain administrator has prohibited sharing files outside of a domain. If that is not the case either, then you should open an issue with the issue tracker

Comment: Setting let share documents outside the organization. You suggest the issue tracker for Google App Script?

Comment: Created the [issue 2030](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2030).

Answer (score 0):

I had a different but similar use case and problem. Like you, my source file was accessible to anyone with the link and my domain settings allowed users to share content outside my domain. It worked for me but not for them.

This might work for you, it has for me (so far):

Assuming you have your original script...

1. Create a separate script for 'Script as web app'.
2. Write a function (e.g. loadFileIds()) to store the necessary fileIds using ScriptDb. Run the loadFileIds() function.
3. Write another function (e.g. getFileId()) in the same project that returns your desired file Id from ScriptDb.getMyDb when called. Avoid using DocsList in this function. I originally thought that because getFileId() would 'run as me' that it would be OK but it was always the DocsList line that caused failures when other users triggered the script.
4. In File > Manage Versions: Save a version of the project.
5. Under Publish: Deploy that version of your project as a web app. Choose Execute the app as "**me(me@mydomain.com)**" and set Who has access to the web app to "**Anyone**".
6. In your original project go to Manage Resources and enter the Project Key of the web app, choose a version and copy the identifier.
7. Write a function that calls yourIdentifier.getFileId() and - hopefully - returns the fileId.

In my experience so far external users have been able to access files that they could not when DocsList methods returned null. But there is one more thing to add... You might find you have to share your web app script with your users. I haven't quite made certain that's necessary but I've encountered bugs when I don't. I untick the option to email them the link.

I learned how to do this from [examples in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb), [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lJewIWVI5s&feature=plcp) and of course StackOverflow.

As you can see, I'm still working this out myself and testing of the system has so far been just me simulating other users. So no promises. Good luck! I'll star your issue.